# Trigger Jenkins from gogs webhook with param

Tags: jenkins, webhooks, gogs

I have a webook url http://jenskinsserver/gogs-webhook/?job=build which will trigger the jenkins job on any event from gogs.

Now i want to trigger a parameterized job and i want the param to be sent via webhook url. How to add params in gogs webhook url?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `Build Remote Trigger` for this to happen. Go to`Build Triggers` => `Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)` and set the API Token.

You have to configure the `General` => `This project is parameterized` and choose whatever you like from the parameters available.

Now in the url, `http://jenskinsserver/gogs-webhook/buildWithParameters?token=<api token provided>&param1=value1&param2=value2` provide params like this and access them by using `$param1`, `$param2` in the scripts.

Comment: i have not used API token can u provide any link for refernce. API Token is any string that we provide in jenkins and webhook?

Comment: API token is kinda secret that you have to provide. You can simply [use this website](http://www.thebitmill.com/tools/password.html) to generate `without punctuation` random string and paste it there.

Comment: 'No valid crumb was included in the request' Getting 403 error

Comment: Can you post your url once??

Comment: my webhook url will look like this http://172.28.105.1:8082/gogs-webhook/buildWithParameters?token=I5kzHWJgdb&Project=logging

Comment: `Use the following URL to trigger build remotely: JENKINS_URL/view/Development%20Workflow/job/spock-development/build?token=TOKEN_NAME or /buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME
Optionally append &cause=Cause+Text to provide text that will be included in the recorded build cause.` I do think you read this. Please access url like this.

Comment: '/view/Development%20Workflow/job/spock-development/' this part should be as it is?

URL: http://server:port/view/Development%20Workflow/job/spock-development/build?token=I5kzHWJgdb

Comment: i am sry `/view/<View Name>` is optional and my jenkins specific and final url in your case is like `JENKINS_URL/job/<job name>/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME&Project=logging`